# Compare the first item with all the items from the second list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to compare the first item of the list with all the items from the second list and then continue to the second item from the first list and compare it with all the the items from the second list and then the same for the third item of the first list.

Example:

```
first = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
second = ['two' , 'one' ,'three']
```

`'one'` (from first `var`) compared with `'two', 'one', 'three'` (from second) if it finds something equal from the second list return true.

Comment: ```return [x==y for x in first for y in second]```

Comment: Seems like homework. What did you try? Where are you stuck? Posting questions on Stack Overflow rather than puzzling it out by yourself is not an optimal way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The involved contains-check is done repeatedly so it should be performed on a set (where it is `O(1)`):

```
s = set(second)
```

Then, you want short-circuiting for which you can use `any`:

```
match = any(x in s for x in first)  # stops on first hit

# or, collecting the matched items
matches = [x for x in first if x in s ]
```

You could compile these two into a one-liner, using the underlying dunder method directly:

```
match = any(map(set(second).__contains__, first))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Use 2 `for`loops

```
def compare(first,second):
    return [x==y for x in first for y in second] #====Return a list of True or False
```

Or

```
def compare(first,second):
    return any(x==y for x in first for y in second) #====Returns True or False
```

Comment: Put `any()` around the returned list and you'll get the correct result.

Comment: @mama I interpreted the question to return ```True``` whenever the values match

Answer (score 0):

An idiomatic way to do this is with sets.

```
first = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
second = ['two', 'one', 'three']
result = bool(set(first) & set(second))
print(result)
```

Comment: Seems to do too much work since it does no short-circuiting when a match is found (`bool()` itself does short-circuiting, but you construct both sets and their intersection in their entirety)

Comment: True. But in many cases --including, perhaps, the one here -- that is not a significant performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

To put your exact words into code, this is how it looks.

```
first = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
second = ['two', 'one' ,'three']

for i in first:
    for j in second:
        if i == j:
            print(f'First: {i}\tSecond: {j}')
            print(True)
```

```
First: one  Second: one
True
First: two  Second: two
True
First: three    Second: three
True
```